# How to find a Sum of N terms of Fibonacci?

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

As we know Fibonacci is represented by this recurrence relation.
$$ F[n]= F[n-1] + F[n-2] $$
How to find a general expression for $ S[n] $ where the Series $ S $ represents the sum of Fibonnaci Till N terms,
 How to find a generalized formulae for $ S[n] $ , As this problem is a pretty standard Coding Problem and Math Stack exchange had no question discussing this I picked  this up to show it how to derive an expression of it .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ F[n-1] = F[n+1] - F[n] $$
As this is the recurrence for Fibonacci , $$ F[n+1]=F[n]+ F[n-1] $$
So we can write this expression by and LHS , RHS shift as => $$F[n-1]=F[n+1]-F[n]$$
So this also holds true => $$ F[n] = F[n+2] - F[n+1] $$
Also, $$F[n-1] = F[n+1] - F[n]$$
$$ F[n-2] = F[n] - F[n-1] $$
$$ F[n-3] = F[n-1] - F[n-2] $$
$$ F[n-4] = F[n-2] - F[n-3] $$
=> till $n=0$
$$ F[0]= F[2]-F[1]$$
If we add up all the equations  we will get this result 
$$ F[0] + F[1] + F[2] + .. F[n]= F[n+2] - F[1] $$
$F[0] + F[1] + F[2] + .. F[n]$ = $S[n] $
$S[n]$ is the series of Sum
so  $$ S[n] = F[n+2] - F[1] $$
We all know $F[1] = 1 $ 
So We Finally get this Equation => $$ S[n] = F[n+2] - 1 $$
This the result for sum of till $n^{th}$ Fibonacci. 
***Fibonacci series is so beautiful*** I would love to hear about some more patterns about it If Anyone could mention it as well or any other way to determin this sum series .